# Input_formats to DateTimeField

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a DateTimeField :

```
 start_time=forms.DateTimeField(input_formats='%y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

and in html

```
   {{form.start_time}}
```

but no matter what i entre in th field, like: 2013-07-07 19:00
it will always give me an error : enter valid date/time, what is worng here? Thanks in Advance

Comment: It doesn't seem very likely, but is it possible that somehow the locale is set to 12h and you're using a 24h time?

Comment: not sure whether it is the problem, but I think '%y' means '13' rather than '2013'

Comment: I agree with Jerry, try with a upper-case Y: `input_formats='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'`

Comment: tried that , didn't work :(

Comment: @ubik , how can i chnage locale to 24h? but when django prints out current time is in 24 h

Comment: @hln, no idea. But if it prints it in 24h then it should be OK...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Write the definition like this:

```
start_time=forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'])
```

Note that input_formats is a list and the Y is upper case. That should work.

Comment: what version of django are you guys using? I'm using 1.5.1 and am unable to use the input_formats argument.

Answer (score 1):

Just did some trial and error. When specifying `input_formats` you have to consider that for a widget `format='whatevers in here'` is a string whereas `input_formats=['whatevers in here', 'whatever else']` is a list.